# The controller must return a response, array given

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am trying to follow [Will Durand's tutorial](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/) on how to set up a good REST API with Symfony2. However I am failing in the very beginning as I get this error:

```
The controller must return a response (Array(welcome => Welcome to my API) given).
```

Something basic must be wrong with my very basic configuration. I have tried different setting for the `fos_rest` config, but the [configuration reference](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration-reference.md) doesn't provide to be very helpful as I do not really understand what the single settings do.

My setup:

```
//config.yml
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: true

fos_rest: ~
```

```
//Controller
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\ApiBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

class DefaultController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array(
            'welcome' => 'Welcome to my API'
        );
    }
}
```

My API should return XML oder JSON based on the accept header. There will never be an html output.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I fixed it!
The config needs to look like this:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: false

fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
```

Comment: I think, it should be added in the official docs (please contact them and submit it). Because it doesn't exist up today. Congrats!

Comment: Just submitting related error message from logs, so that people can find this via google: `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'You need to disable the view annotations in SensioFrameworkExtraBundle when using the FOSRestBundle View Response listener.' in /home/jupiter/symfony/dimsym/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ConfigurationCheckPass.php:27`

Answer (score 4):

I spending a day for searching working configuration:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:   {   annotations: false }
    router: {   annotations: true }

fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```